# 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter, azure-hdinsight

I´ve got an issue trying to replicate the example I saw here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-load-data-run-query.

It seems to fail when it comes to : `hvacTable = sqlContext.createDataFrame(hvac)`
 and the error it returns is:

```
'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 333, in createDataFrame
    return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1124, in __call__
    args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1094, in _build_args
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 289, in get_command_part
    command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

I´m following the example to a T, it´s a pyspark notebook in Jupyter.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: try this : `hvac.take(1)`. What is the output ?

Comment: Thank you Steven, I´m just about to leave work so I´ll try your suggestion tomorrow and revert with the output.  Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

you probably running it on newer cluster. Please update "sqlContext" to "spark" to get it to work. We'll update this doc article as well.

Also in Spark 2.x you can now do this operation with DataFrames which simpler. You can replace the snippet creating hvac table with following equivalent:

```
csvFile = spark.read.csv('wasb:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
csvFile.write.saveAsTable("hvac")
```